# How to read from a CSV file in Python while still maintaining single responsibility principle?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, single-responsibility-principle

When reading from a file, I save the read in as a dictionary like this:

```
with open('StudentsPerformance.csv', 'r') as file:
    read_csv = csv.DictReader(file)
   
    # Find the minimum math score
    min_math_score = 0
    for row in read_csv:
        math_score = int(row['math score'])

        if math_score < min_math_score:
            min_math_score = math_score
```

But I would like to iterate through the read_csv variable outside of the "with open" function. How can I do this without getting a:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can first read the whole file and then perform the operations on the full file later on. Alternatively you can create a function outside the `with` statement and call that function instead to perform the preprocessing.

Comment: @Thymen I think the latter makes sense to me, not sure what you mean by perform the operations on the full file later on the whole file later on. Thank you.

Comment: I mean that you first read the whole file to memory and then perform the operations outside the with statement. This will be fine for small files, but definitely not the go through approach for large files.

Comment: The file is automatically closed outside the `with` block. That's the point of the `with` block. Please include a complete [mre]. Also read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!